# Merge multiple transparent png imagick not working

Tags: php, imagick

I have created the below code to paste the two images on top of each other however i keep getting a blank screen when i run this code

```
enter code here
$imagick = new Imagick('A-hair.png');
echo ($imagick);
// Add another image in the same object
$imagick->addImage(new Imagick('a-Collar'));
// Set the Opacity
$imagick->setImageOpacity(1.0);
// Merge the Layers
$result = $imagick->mergeImageLayers(11);
// Display the image
header("Content-Type: image/png");
echo $result->getImageBlob();
```

[A-hair.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUonA.png)
[a-Collar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFfPm.png)

I have checked for compatibility and got the message that Imagick is compatible

Comment: Doesn't `setImageOpacity(1.0)` make all transparent areas non-transparent? _This method operates on all channels, which means that for example opacity value of 0.5 will set all transparent areas to partially opaque._ You might also want to change the opacity before adding images or merging layers. You should also use the constant when calling `mergeImageLayers` - I have no idea what 11 means.

Comment: Hi MatsLindh thanks for the suggestion, I have tried changing opacity but no result :( The merge Image Layers attribute is LAYERMETHOD_REMOVEZERO